# script recording and playback, and excel

Tags: sap-gui

I want to automate a transaction on SAP using the playback script. 
I record a transaction and then export it under excellent all while remaining on SAP, it works perfectly. (this is the Microsoft Excel icon, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>), this is an icon with an Excel sheet and a green cross on it.

When I open my script and execute it, the script itself works, the export works but there is no data when it existed when I did the transaction by hand.
I don't see why.

This happens in SAP GUI.

```
  If Not IsObject(App) Then
  Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set App = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
   End If
  If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
  Set Connection = App.Children(0)
   End If
   If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
    WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
    WScript.ConnectObject App, "on"
     End If
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
     session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "S_ALR_87012284"
       .......
      session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/
        shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").setDocument 1, ""
```

When I look at the excel sheet on SAP, I see that "/" and the sheet is called "~SAP{7BD014FE-F4CF-49DA-AAD5-FD"

Yet when I do it by hand, I see all my data.

Answer (score 0):

Please deactivate the last command and it should work again.

```
 ...
 session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
 session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "S_ALR_87012284"
 ...
 'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/
    shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").setDocument 1, ""
```

Regards, ScriptMan

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's better than before but I still have the excel sheet without data.

Comment: If you do not see any data, it can hardly be better. My test script ends as follows:                                         session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[43]").press
'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").setDocument 1,""                                                                and I can see everything.